# is there a way to see all changes been done on a wordpress site?

Tags: revisions

I was asked to overtake a website created by wordpress.org.
The former IT did not do anything on the website since 2015 and I got asked to prove it. 
I can see the revisions but my boss wants it to be listed on one page.. 
Is there a way to do it?

Cheers 
Anne

Comment: Welcome to WPSE @Ulya, 2015? ugh. Revisions for posts/pages/cpt's you mean? When you want to have 'prove' for some that isn't done, there is imho none. As long YOU didn't touch any (meaning by that updating and more) you could try and read out the dates of the WordPress folders/files to have at least some. And pray for server back-up logfiles, take 10liter coffee and start reading them (last login of those ITers and last update of WordPress/Plugins etc)  I would go for virtual domain log-files when they exist at all. Anyway Good luck from this side.

Comment: thanks for the response :) Yea it might take cans of coffee... he still tries to destroy the work ... Its just a pitty...

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is way too late and you could have finished the job. But you can use the Internet Archive. This is the link: https://web.archive.org/

Answer (score 0):

The person could have worked on the website via code/file edits or admin/database updates.  If you're interested in code/file edits, review the timestamps on the files on the server.  If you're interested in the admin/database updates and have direct access to the database, take a look at the `wp_posts` table and sort by the `post_modified` column as a starting point.